# Application.Ontime giving inaccurate results

Tags: excel, vba

When I run the code below (test1), I get varying results, almost always around 2.5 sec - rarely is it 3 secs.  I could understand it being higher than 3 secs if the computer was occupied with something else, but less than 3 makes no sense.  I've tried this with xl2003 and xl2010, with similar results.  I hope someone can explain this to me.

```
Option Explicit

Dim t As Double

Sub test1()
    Debug.Print Now
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "test2", , True
    '  t = Timer
End Sub

Sub test2()
    Debug.Print Now
    ' Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub
```

Comment: I've changed my code, and now I seem to be getting accurate results.  Maybe Timer was causing the inconsistency before.

Answer (score 0):

`Now()` and `Timer` seem to update their values asynchronously.  In some quick tests I get a variance ranging from approx 0 to 1 second.

As you have discovered you should stick to one source of time.  As an aside, `OnTime` can only be scheduled in increments of 1 second.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my comment.  In my initial post, I was using Timer exclusively, and getting varied results.  In the edited code, I've commented out the Timer lines, and am now using Now to get the elapsed time (by doing a mental subtraction of the 2 "Now's").  So Timer & Now were used exclusively - but with the latter I always had consistent 3sec results.  Which leads me to wonder about the accuracy of Timer.